# Is suicide forbidden in the Qur'an?

Tags: quran, tafseer, suicide

Why is suicide a sin in Islam?

I only know of 34/29 in Qur'an-- rather advising you not to do so than forbidding it.

> And they say, "When is this promise, if you should be truthful?"  Say, "For you is the appointment of a Day [when] you will not remain thereafter an hour, nor will you precede [it]."  -- [Qur'an 34:29-30](https://quran.com/34/29)

Hurting others is a sin, and a great one to my knowledge. 
There are many good people who killed themselves rather than living a disgraceful life. Some of them did so just because they 
didn't have the "skills" to step on others.

The only thing i can think of is that suicide is rejecting God's word that He doesn't give you a heavier load than you can carry, and that everything is a test, improves your soul to a higher level.

Why is suicide a sin in Islam?

Where in Qur'an said so?

Note: I'm nowhere near talking about suicide bombing or any other political aspects of it.

Comment: If you think that hurting others is a sin, then it clearly follows that hurting yourself is a sin.

Comment: @Hakim - true, but there's a difference. it's on you. you don't owe anything to others hurting yourself.

Answer (score 6):

The most important reason is that human being cannot put himself in place of God. Means there are some functions which only God is permitted to do not human. And about this issue God tells us that He gives life and he takes life, see this verses in Quran:

> - "He gives life and causes death, and to Him you will be
>     returned."(**Surat Yūnus,verse56**)
> - "... When Abraham said, "My Lord is the one who gives life and causes
>     death" ..."(**Surat Al-Baqarah,verse 258**)

Life is given to each person for God's purpose. And we can't decide when our purpose is finished and we should die, surely This is known only to God. So If we take or attempt to take our own life (suicide) we are trying to perform a function that belongs to God.

We are being tested For as long as we live in this world. We should be gratefulness to God for whatever situation we are confronted with. Every situation is a test for us and Suicide isn't the way to be delivered from bad situations.

> "And do not kill yourselves [or one another]. Indeed, Allah is to you
>   ever Merciful."(**Surat An-Nisā',verse 29**)

God has made life sacred for human beings, and it is mentioned in Quran:

> "Say: "Come, I will rehearse what God hath (really) prohibited you
>   from": Join not anything as equal with Him; be good to your parents;
>   kill not your children on a plea of want;- We provide sustenance for
>   you and for them;- come not nigh to shameful deeds. Whether open or
>   secret; take not life, which God hath made sacred, except by way of
>   justice and law.This has He instructed you that you may use
>   reason."(**Surat Al-'An`ām,verse 151**)

So, we can't easily take our life.

Also,There are many verses against suicide in the Qur’an.The following verses make the prohibition very clear:

> - "And spend in the way of Allah and do not throw [yourselves] with your
>     [own] hands into destruction [by refraining]. And do good; indeed,
>     Allah loves the doers of good."(**Surat Al-Baqarah,verse 195**)
> - "How can you disbelieve in Allah when you were lifeless and He brought
>     you to life; then He will cause you to die, then He will bring you
>     [back] to life, and then to Him you will be returned."(**Surat
>     Al-Baqarah,verse 28**)

In addition intentional murder of human beings is forbidden in Islam. The murdering of oneself (ourselves) is also included in that prohibition. God says in the Qur’an:

> - "But whoever kills a believer intentionally - his recompense is Hell,
>     wherein he will abide eternally, and Allah has become angry with him
>     and has cursed him and has prepared for him a great
>     punishment."(**Surat An-Nisā',verse 93**)
> - "...if any one slew a person - unless it be for murder or for
>     spreading mischief in the land - it would be as if he slew the whole
>     people: and if any one saved a life, it would be as if he saved the
>     life of the whole people..."(**Surat Al-Mā'idah,verse 32**)

So, killing ourselves is equal to killing All Muslims.

At the end we should know deciding about life and death is belong to Allah.

For more details see [this page](http://www.ascertainthetruth.com/att/index.php/al-islam/al-islam-and-suicide/131-suicide-and-islam-a-deeper-perspective).

Comment: When someone kills him/herself, that person is not putting him/herself in Allah (swt)'s position, that's not possible because he/she would not be able to kill him/herself without Allah (swt)'s permission to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

> 4:29, And do not kill yourselves [or one another]. Indeed, Allaah is to you ever Merciful

True its on you and it does not affect the people around you, and it's your own choice, but what is your purpose in life? Why did god create us?

> 51:56 And I did not create the jinn and mankind except to worship Me.

Our mission in life is not to fulfill our desires and make life our entire concerns, rather it is to worship God and follow his orders.

> 23:115 "Did you think that We had created you in play (without any purpose), and that you would not be brought back to Us?"

We all face difficult times within our life but the beauty of it is that for each one of us we only have burden for what we are capable of.

> 2:286 Allah does not charge a soul except [with that within] its capacity. It will have [the consequence of] what [good] it has gained, and it will bear [the consequence of] what [evil] it has earned.

Every difficulty we face in our life's is only temporarily and not lasting forever no matter how long it is or how short.

> 94:5 For indeed, with hardship [will be] ease.
> 94:6 Indeed, with hardship [will be] ease.

What matters is how we react in such difficulties, after all we receive a judgment of how we spent our life's.

> 99:7 So whoever does an atom's weight of good will see it,99:8 And whoever does an atom's weight of evil will see it.

God has chosen to create you and give you life, what do you chose to do instead?? take that life away!! in another context imagine yourself feeding a hungry person and offering him food but rather he spits on the food, would that not make you furious.

> Suicide is a major sin. The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) stated that the one who commits suicide will be punished with something like that with which he killed himself.
>
> Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) narrated that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever throws himself down from a mountain and kills himself will be in the Fire of Hell, throwing himself down therein for ever and ever. Whoever takes poison and kills himself, his poison will be in his hand and he will be sipping it in the Fire of Hell for ever and ever. Whoever kills himself with a piece of iron, that piece of iron will be in his hand and he will be stabbing himself in the stomach with it in the Fire of Hell, for ever and ever.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari, 5442; Muslim, 109.

What ever we do in the current life is recorded, we do good we will receive good otherwise we do evil and will receive evil, as stated in the above hadith the one who commits suicide will be punished by the means he committed suicide with for ever and ever, so would you rather end your life to even stay longer in misery and torture or would you choose to be patient and good upon difficulties to only receive good i the hereafter.