# Is it possible to repent from suicide?

Tags: tawba, suicide

Suicide is haram; see e.g. [Qur'an 4:29](https://quran.com/4/29) (*do not kill yourselves [or one another]*) and [What does Islam say about suicide?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/323/17163) and [Is suicide forbidden in the Qur'an?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17592/17163).  However, while suicide is often pictured as a fairly short process, the reality may be blurrier:

1. Try to kill oneself.
2. Don't immediately succeed, but irreparably damage one's body.
3. Subsequently die from the damage.

E.g. if someone drank poison, it may take hours to years before it resulted in the person's death.

When suicide is not immediate, it may be possible to sincerely repent to Allah before inevitably dying from suicide.

**Question**: Is it possible to repent from suicide?

While forgiveness is mentioned in the Qur'an [Qur'an 39:53](https://quran.com/39/53) (*Indeed, Allah forgives all sins.*), ahadith such as [Sahih al-Bukhari 1363, 1364](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/23/117) (*My slave has caused death on himself hurriedly, so I forbid Paradise for him*) indicate a prolonged punishment for suicide.

Comment: @Uma, this hadith would be a good answer to the question as it shows the potential of repenting (or being otherwise forgiven) for suicide.

Comment: If a believer killed himself, then the doors of repentance is closed and this person cannot ask His forgiveness, this person my taste the sever punishment but after this, he can go to Heaven, but if a disbeliever killed himself with rejecting the Truth, then this person will go to Hell forever.

Comment: And if you just pretended that you want to kill yourself but you have not done this, it is better to seek God’s forgiveness for this.

Answer (score 1):

If one repents when they have any hope or chance of living and their death is not imminent then their repentance is acceptable as they have not crossed the threshold after which repentance is rejected:

> وليست التوبة للذين يعملون السيئات حتى إذا حضر أحدهم الموت قال إني تبت الآن
>
> But repentance is not [accepted] of those who [continue to] do evil deeds up until, when death comes to one of them, he says, "Indeed, I have repented now,"
>
> <sup>— [Quran 4:18](https://quran.com/4/18?translations=20)</sup>

> ‏ إن الله عز وجل ليقبل توبة العبد ما لم يغرغر
>
> Allah accepts the repentance of His slave so long as the death rattle has not yet reached his throat.
>
> <sup>— [Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:4253)</sup>

Specifically regarding suicide:

> وأيضا فالتعليل بأنه لا توبة له مشكل على قواعد أهل السنة والجماعة لإطلاق النصوص في قبول توبة العاصي، بل التوبة من الكفر مقبولة قطعا وهو أعظم وزرا، ولعل المراد ما إذا تاب حالة اليأس كما إذا فعل بنفسه ما لا يعيش معه عادة كجرح مزهق في ساعته وإلقاء في بحر أو نار فتاب، أما لو جرح نفسه، وبقي حيا أياما مثلا ثم تاب ومات فينبغي الجزم بقبول توبته
>
> The saying of some that there is no repentance (for one who commits suicide) is problematic according to the principles of the Ahl al-Sunnah wa'l-Jamaa'ah, because the texts on acceptance of repentance for sins are categorical, rather even repentance from kufr is accepted categorically and that is the greatest of sins. Perhaps it means that his repentance is not accepted in the state when he has despaired of living any longer by doing something to himself where he typically can't remain alive such as by inflicting a wound which would kill quickly or throwing himself into a sea or into fire. However if he injures himself and remains alive for some days for example and then repents and dies then his repentance should certainly be accepted
>
> <sup>— [Haashiyat Ibn ‘Aabideen](https://shamela.ws/book/21613/868)</sup>

Additionally suicide by a Muslim may be forgiven by Allah even in the absence of repentance as evident in the [hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/218). That is because suicide is not kufr and every sin other than kufr is subject to the will of Allah, He may forgive it or punish for it. And if He punishes for it that will be for a finite time and the person will eventually enter paradise.

Answer (score -1):

Repentance is always possible for any sin, including suicide. In Islam, we believe that Allah is the Most Merciful and Forgiving. However, it is important to understand that suicide is a grave sin and a violation of the sanctity of life.

In the Qur'an, Allah says in Surah An-Nisa (4:29):

وَلَا تَقْتُلُوا أَنفُسَكُمْ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ كَانَ بِكُمْ رَحِيمًا

"And do not kill yourselves [or one another]. Indeed, Allah is to you ever Merciful."

This verse clearly prohibits taking one's own life. However, it does not mean that repentance is impossible. Allah's mercy is vast and He forgives those who sincerely repent.

In a hadith narrated by Abu Hurairah (may Allah be pleased with him), the Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said, "Whoever kills himself with something in this world will be punished with it on the Day of Resurrection." (Sahih al-Bukhari 5700)

This hadith emphasizes the seriousness of the act of suicide and its consequences. However, it does not negate the possibility of repentance and forgiveness.

To seek repentance, one must sincerely regret their actions, turn to Allah in sincere repentance, and strive to make amends. It is important to seek forgiveness from Allah, as only He has the power to forgive sins.

It is also recommended to seek guidance and support from knowledgeable scholars or counselors who can provide guidance and help in overcoming the challenges one may face.

Remember, Allah's mercy is vast, and He forgives those who sincerely repent. May Allah guide us all and grant us His forgiveness.